# How to use the semantic ui styling?

Tags: tabulator

thanks for the great plugin, really loving it!
I am using the tabulator from CDN, like this;

```
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.1/dist/js/jquery_wrapper.min.js"></script>
```

I know that the documentation says something about using the semantic UI theme, but I do not understand how I can do this. I am using semantic UI locally, but as mentioned, the tabulator is being used through a cdn.
How can I use:

```
<link href="/dist/css/semantic-ui/tabulator_semantic-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Like mentioned in the docs? Would be terrific with a working example on how to use this, because I love the semantic UI theme I have seen in the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the link that pulls in the ***tabulator.min.css*** stylesheet with one that pulls in the ***tabulator_semantic-ui.min.css*** stylesheet

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.1/dist/css/semantic-ui/tabulator_semantic-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```